# Angular throws error in Firefox for date format

Tags: angular

I get this error in Firefox: "InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "NaN-NaN-NaN" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'" but in chrome it works fine.

I want to show the dates from database in a format like this: 2020-01-01.

Here's my code:

```
formatDate(date) {
    let d: Date = new Date(date),
      month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
      day = '' + d.getDate(),
      year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2)
      month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2)
      day = '0' + day;
    return [year, month, day].join('-');
  }
```

and my html:

```
<td>{{irregularday.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of console.log(irregularday.date), why your paste formatDate() function here?

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding moment to your project - the function above does not look right and dates are very difficult in JS. - https://momentjs.com/.